# How to remove a blank page between two abstracts

Tags: page

I'm writing my Bachelor's thesis in English in a Finnish university. Therefore, I have to have two separate abstract pages, one in Finnish and one in English. With only one abstract I had:

```latex
\begin{abstract}
Abstract text here
\end{abstract}
```

and there was no additional blank page after it. To add another abstract, I simply tried:

```latex
\begin{abstract}
Abstract text here
\end{abstract}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract text here
\end{abstract}
```

and a blank page appeared between the abstracts. I'm not sure what information I should give but here's the beginning of the file:

```latex
\documentclass[english,oneside,openright,utf]{HYgradu}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color, graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex, plainpages=false, bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage[footnotesize,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}

\onehalfspacing
```

I already tried:

```latex
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
```

and

```latex
\nopagebreak
```

and

```latex
\usepackage[clearempty]{titlesec}
```

but they didn't seem to work. I'm not sure if I put them in right places, though. I'm not experienced with LaTeX.

EDIT: I had \clearpage in the custom class HYgradu.cls file at the end of the \renewenvironment{abstract}{}:

...

\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\if@twoside
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage    
\fi

\ifdefined@quoting
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagebreak
\hspace{0pt}
\vfill
\noindent @quoting
\vfill
\hspace{0pt}
\pagebreak
\fi

}

I just removed \clearpage and now it seems to work fine: no more blank page between the abstracts. So, my custom class was a bit different after all from the one behind the link in the comment. Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You are using the customized class file `HYgradu.cls`,

Comment: To elaborate, we don't have `HYgradu.cls`, so we can't compile your example.  If I make a simple example with two abstracts, they appear next to each other, so it seems that your class is doing something to insert the blank page.  You could probably try changing `openright` to `openany`, but that will also change how other chapters are typeset.

Comment: Is [this `Hygradu` class](https://github.com/dronir/HYgradu/blob/master/HYgradu.cls), which you are using? But in this case, you cannot use `\usepackage[titletoc](appendix}`, because `\appendices` would already be defined by the class.  And if I try to make a complete example from your code snippets, I get a blank page before the abstracts but not between them. So can you please link the class and also show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) instead of code snippets only?

Comment: Yes, that class behind the link looks the same as mine. Changing openright to openany didn't work. I have to look at the class more carefully.

Comment: Alternatively you could put both abstracts in one `abstract` environment (possibly in two columns).

Comment: Sorry, my custom class was a bit different after all from the one behind the link. I had \clearpage at the end of \renewenvironment{abstract}{}. I just removed that and now it works fine. Thanks for help!